# Unable to deploy app on heroku getting error "Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script."

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

This is the log I'm getting

2021-11-27T17:10:11.459943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2021-11-27T17:10:11.459977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.

2021-11-27T17:10:11.460015+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2021-11-27T17:10:11.465735+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:10:11.465817+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2021-11-27T17:10:11.465857+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-27T17_10_11_460Z-debug.log

2021-11-27T17:10:11.603857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-11-27T17:10:11.669435+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-11-27T17:17:22.015316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ecommerce918.herokuapp.com request_id=cf1b3cbc-d850-45bf-80c2-464af583620c fwd="49.36.44.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-11-27T17:17:24.778971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ecommerce918.herokuapp.com request_id=8965ce73-275e-4047-8b28-7491e5cf2f0b fwd="49.36.44.85" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2021-11-27T17:24:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xsymphony91@gmail.com

2021-11-27T17:24:25.012463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-11-27T17:24:23.503323+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user xsymphony91@gmail.com

2021-11-27T17:24:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2021-11-27T17:24:23.503323+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ab767198 by user xsymphony91@gmail.com

2021-11-27T17:24:27.104406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2021-11-27T17:24:27.890733+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:27.890745+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app

2021-11-27T17:24:27.890746+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js

2021-11-27T17:24:27.890746+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987855+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987856+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987857+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987857+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987857+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Users'

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987857+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987858+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Module/usersModule.js

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987858+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Routes/users.js

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987858+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987859+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/Module/usersModule.js:1:14)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987862+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/Module/usersModule.js',

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987863+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/Routes/users.js',

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987864+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/index.js'

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987864+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]

2021-11-27T17:24:27.987864+00:00 app[web.1]: }

2021-11-27T17:24:27.994859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2021-11-27T17:24:27.995040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1

2021-11-27T17:24:27.998258+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`

2021-11-27T17:24:27.998304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1

2021-11-27T17:24:27.998355+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2021-11-27T17:24:27.998392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.

2021-11-27T17:24:27.998428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2021-11-27T17:24:28.001250+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:28.001322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2021-11-27T17:24:28.001356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-27T17_24_27_998Z-debug.log

2021-11-27T17:24:28.106670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-11-27T17:24:28.226427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2021-11-27T17:24:28.229907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2021-11-27T17:24:30.284262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2021-11-27T17:24:31.602815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2021-11-27T17:24:31.346119+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.346134+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start /app

2021-11-27T17:24:31.346135+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js

2021-11-27T17:24:31.346135+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447425+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447426+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw err;

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447427+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447427+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447427+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Users'

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447428+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447430+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Module/usersModule.js

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447431+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/Routes/users.js

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447431+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/Module/usersModule.js:1:14)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447433+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447434+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447434+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447434+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447435+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447435+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447435+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/Module/usersModule.js',

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447436+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/Routes/users.js',

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447436+00:00 app[web.1]:     '/app/index.js'

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447436+00:00 app[web.1]:   ]

2021-11-27T17:24:31.447436+00:00 app[web.1]: }

2021-11-27T17:24:31.454258+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2021-11-27T17:24:31.454440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1

2021-11-27T17:24:31.457946+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`

2021-11-27T17:24:31.457992+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1

2021-11-27T17:24:31.458050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2021-11-27T17:24:31.458089+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.

2021-11-27T17:24:31.458125+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

2021-11-27T17:24:31.462491+00:00 app[web.1]:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.462593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

2021-11-27T17:24:31.462642+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-27T17_24_31_458Z-debug.log

2021-11-27T17:24:31.684068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

here is my package.json --->

```
        {
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node index.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^6.0.13",
        "razorpay": "^2.8.0"
      }
    }
```

Here is my index.js--->

```
const express = require("express");
const mongo = require("./connection");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const usersRouter = require("./Routes/users");
const productsRouter = require("./Routes/products");
const purchasesRouter = require("./Routes/purchases");
const orderRouter = require("./Routes/order");
const authorization = require("./Module/authorization");
require("dotenv").config();

app.use(cors());
//connection db

async function loadapp() {
  try {
    await mongo.connect();
    app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello!");
});

//routes
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/products", productsRouter);

//middleware for authentication
app.use(authorization.auth);

//protected route
app.use("/purchases", purchasesRouter);
app.use("/order", orderRouter);

app.listen(port);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
loadapp();
```

Comment: That's only part of your error log. Please [edit] your question and show _all_ the errors, not just the parts you think are relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much for diverting me towards the right direction, I was checking the logs and then I found one spelling mistake , changing that fixed the problem . 
What's weird is that it my running well in my laptop .